# Spark - "sc.parallelize()" run time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i have a question about the run time of the "parallelize" function.

When i call this line of code:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(data, numSlices)
```

My data is a list of size ~50, where every object is 10Mb size.

My question is this:

When i ran the following line:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 1)
```

It took it about 1-2 seconds to run.
But, when i tried to increase the number of partitions:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 20)
```

The run time increased to about 20 seconds.

I tried to look into the spark code, and the "readRDDFromFile" function code, but couldnt see any reason why would the number of slices change the run time.

Note: If the list is about 100 members and not 50, it falls on  - 
"PySpark: java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space"

I guess i can increase the heap space to solve the error, but i will still have the issue of really slow run time, when actually trying to use partitions.

So, trying to understand why it takes so long to call parallelize when i increase the number of slices.

Thanks!

Comment: Was this the only piece of code?

Comment: what does JVM memory analysis show? you could do that with live jvm for example

Comment: Are you running spark in local mode or cluster mode? If its in local mode, how many cores did you allocate?

Comment: its not the only piece of code, but there wasnt much more. just a list of ~10 mb objects. list was about 150.
So calling sc.parallelize with the full list killed the java heap space, but when i call it with just [0:50] of the list, it worked, just took much longer when i used 20 partitions instead of 1.

How can i see the JVM memory analysis while running that?

thanks!